# Entity Framework - lazy loading failing but eager loading fine - how to fix/debug?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, poco, entity-framework-4.3.1

I am using entity framework 4.3.1 against a sql server 2012 database and I have a database with these tables (there are more but the relevant bits are below):

```
Customer

    CustomerNumber nvarchar(10) not null primary key

SalesDocument

    SalesDocumentNumber nvarchar(10) not null primary key
    CustomerNumber nvarchar(10) not null
```

I am running the following snippet of code:

```
const string docNumber = "111348718";
IQueryable<SalesDocument> docs = factory.CreateSalesDocumentRepository().All;

var ssd = docs.Single(s => s.SalesDocumentNumber.Equals(docNumber));

if (ssd.Customer == null)
    Console.WriteLine("NOOOOOOO");

ssd = docs
    .Include(s => s.Customer)
    .Single(s => s.SalesDocumentNumber.Equals(docNumber));

if (ssd.Customer == null)
    Console.WriteLine("YESSSSSS");
```

and I get **only** NOOOOOOO printed.

So it seems that the lazy loading is not working but eager loading is.

What gives and how on earth can I debug what has gone wrong in this scenario (what are likely causes for this to fail - it feels like a bug in EF to me but I am holding off on declaring that and throwing the whole steaming pile out of the window)?  Surely the configuration is OK if the second one is working fine...?

Comment: There are several reasons why lazy loading might not work, the simplest being that it isn't enabled, or your classes don't meet the requirements for lazy loading. Could you show how your classes are defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mean to teach you to suck eggs, but have you enabled LazyLoading in your `ObjectContext`?

ie: in the ObjectContext constructor

```
 this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Note that this assumes an `ObjectContext` is used. For a `DbContext`, lazy loading is enabled when possible by default, but can be disabled.

Comment: I have exactly that and I am using a DbContext anyway so it should be enabled?

Comment: Arrggghh, but you know what I didn't do!?  I did not have the property as virtual on the entity - thanks hvd and podiluska for making me look again at my configuration